# Как правильно вставлять в сайт иконки

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

Как правильно работать с иконками на сайте?

Как я понимаю, необходимо использовать SVG-иконки. Но такой вопрос, а если надо например, чтобы при наведении цвет иконки менялся?

Comment: Можете картинками, можете svg через стили перекрашивать, можете через [шрифт](https://fontawesome.com/).

Comment: @nazarpunk, могу попросить Вас чуть подробнее по поводу перекрашивания SVG:  есть возможность сделать это через CSS?

Comment: можно и через обычный css вставлять svg без лишних проблем

Comment: вот к примеру обе иконки из обоеих ответов которые я вывел из css в html: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/VwWWmYZ

Comment: @Айболит на мой  взгляд это утонченное извращение. Дважды добавлять код одной и той же иконки с помощью background:url() Первый раз с одним цветом, во второй раз иконка добавляется при наведении  с другим цветом.  Наверное лучше, если уж иконка добавляется background:url(), то изменять её цвет при наведении с помощью css фильтров

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  к примеру  градиент не получится фильтрами сделать а изменить на иконку с градиентом труда не составит, но только разумеется можно сократить чего я ни сделал

Comment: @Айболит было бы хорошо  добавить отдельный ответ по своему комментарию. так как Слова понимаются по разному. Чем больше решений по отдельному вопросу, тем лучше.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT отвечать лень -

Comment: @Айболит тебе же не лень создавать код на codepen и постоянно постить сюда ссылки? Наверное было бы лучше сразу отвечать здесь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы добавляете иконку SVG в HTML документ инлайн, то есть просто копируете код иконки внутрь HTML, то проблем со стилизацией из внешней CSS, вообще нет.

Задаете цвет иконки в исходном состоянии и при наведении.

```css
svg {
    width: 100px;
    } 
 #path {
 fill:black;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 }  
  #path:hover {
   fill:crimson;
  }
```

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'>
  <path id="path" d='M7 15h2v-2h-2v2zm1-14a4 4 90 00-4 4h2c0-1 1-2 2-2s2 1 2 2c0 2-3 2-3 6h2c0-3 3-3 3-6a4 4 90 00-4-4z'/>
</svg>
```

Ещё вариант с использованием css filter drop-shadow

```css
svg {
    width: 100px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    } 
  svg:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px dodgerblue);
  }
```

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'>
  <path d='M7 15h2v-2h-2v2zm1-14a4 4 90 00-4 4h2c0-1 1-2 2-2s2 1 2 2c0 2-3 2-3 6h2c0-3 3-3 3-6a4 4 90 00-4-4z'/>
</svg>
```

**Иконка добавлена из внешнего ресурса с помощью тега `<img>`**

В этом случае цвет иконки можно менять при наведении с помощью фильтров CSS или SVG

```css
img 
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
img:hover {
filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f511.svg">
```

[Другие способы добавления SVG в HTML](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047)

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: Получается, что нет возможности через SVG, существующий отдельно от разметки HTML определить все возможные пути для дальнейшего использования через <use> отдельными SVG? То есть, спрайт-лист определений должен быть зашит в разметку? Есть возможность прикрепить один файл со всеми определениями иконок, через CSS, может быть, или JS?

Comment: @Leonid если добавлен SVG файл с помощью `<img>`, то не возможно его стилизовать обычными правилами CSS, так как это по сути изолированный объект, по поведению ничем не отличается от растровой картинки. Но если добавить svg файл - **спрайт со стороннего ресурса с помощью  `<object>`**, а далее вызывать отдельные иконки из спрайта по ID с помощью <use>  то стилизация, интерактивность вполне возможна. Этому посвящён целый раздел на SO - [svg-спрайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82)

Comment: @Leonid Значит, что-то не так делаешь

Comment: @Leonid пробуй в Frefox, так как Chrome при локальном расположении файла SVG со спрайтом на виртуальном - сервере в целях безопасности не работает.

Comment: @Leonid http://dreamhelg.ru/2017/02/symbol-svg-sprite-detail-guide/

Comment: Помогло!!! Спасибо!!! То есть, даже спрайт прикреплять не надо, просто переделал с `<use xlink:href="#svg-point"></use>`  на `<use xlink:href="sprite.svg#svg-point"></use>`. Это совсем другое дело, теперь и спрайт можно редактировать и в кэше он держаться будет и вообще можно из нескольких спрайтов дергать!!

Comment: @Leonid я думал ты это видел в ответе  **h**  `icons.svg#svg-point`  А вообще-то файл со спрайтом надо добавлять через `object` А то браузеры типа safari оч. консервативны и не сработают

Answer (score 4):

Исходный код иконки конверта:

```
<svg width="16" height="13" viewBox="0 0 16 13" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M16 3.373V10.5C16 11.163 15.7366 11.7989 15.2678 12.2678C14.7989 12.7366 14.163 13 13.5 13H2.5C1.83696 13 1.20107 12.7366 0.732233 12.2678C0.263392 11.7989 0 11.163 0 10.5V3.373L7.746 7.931C7.82295 7.97638 7.91066 8.00032 8 8.00032C8.08934 8.00032 8.17705 7.97638 8.254 7.931L16 3.373ZM13.5 3.09527e-08C14.1151 -9.6716e-05 14.7087 0.226607 15.1672 0.63674C15.6257 1.04687 15.9168 1.61164 15.985 2.223L8 6.92L0.0150001 2.223C0.0831583 1.61164 0.374324 1.04687 0.832795 0.63674C1.29127 0.226607 1.88485 -9.6716e-05 2.5 3.09527e-08H13.5Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Исходный код иконки поинта:

```
<svg width="12" height="17" viewBox="0 0 12 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M5.83333 7.91667C5.2808 7.91667 4.7509 7.69717 4.36019 7.30647C3.96949 6.91577 3.75 6.38587 3.75 5.83333C3.75 5.2808 3.96949 4.7509 4.36019 4.36019C4.7509 3.96949 5.2808 3.75 5.83333 3.75C6.38587 3.75 6.91577 3.96949 7.30647 4.36019C7.69717 4.7509 7.91667 5.2808 7.91667 5.83333C7.91667 6.10692 7.86278 6.37783 7.75808 6.63059C7.65339 6.88335 7.49993 7.11302 7.30647 7.30647C7.11302 7.49993 6.88335 7.65339 6.63059 7.75808C6.37783 7.86278 6.10692 7.91667 5.83333 7.91667V7.91667ZM5.83333 0C4.28624 0 2.80251 0.614582 1.70854 1.70854C0.614582 2.80251 0 4.28624 0 5.83333C0 10.2083 5.83333 16.6667 5.83333 16.6667C5.83333 16.6667 11.6667 10.2083 11.6667 5.83333C11.6667 4.28624 11.0521 2.80251 9.95812 1.70854C8.86416 0.614582 7.38043 0 5.83333 0V0Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

---

Можно вставлять **SVG** код прямо в **HTML** разметку, он может казаться там поначалу чуждым, но это нормальная практика и единственная возможность работать с отдельными его частями. Чтобы поменять цвет через **CSS**, нужно у элементов которые будут перекрашиваться убрать атрибуты `fill` или `stroke` (смотря что будет перекрашиваться).

```css
svg {
  width: 9vmax;
  height: 9vmax;
}

.icon-1 {
  fill: tomato;
  transition: fill 0.4s;
}

.icon-1:hover {
  fill: lightgreen;
}

.icon-2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: tomato;
  transition: stroke 0.4s;
}

.icon-2:hover {
  stroke: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<!-- icon 1 -->
<svg class="icon-1" viewBox="0 0 16 13" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M16 3.373V10.5C16 11.163 15.7366 11.7989 15.2678 12.2678C14.7989 12.7366 14.163 13 13.5 13H2.5C1.83696 13 1.20107 12.7366 0.732233 12.2678C0.263392 11.7989 0 11.163 0 10.5V3.373L7.746 7.931C7.82295 7.97638 7.91066 8.00032 8 8.00032C8.08934 8.00032 8.17705 7.97638 8.254 7.931L16 3.373ZM13.5 3.09527e-08C14.1151 -9.6716e-05 14.7087 0.226607 15.1672 0.63674C15.6257 1.04687 15.9168 1.61164 15.985 2.223L8 6.92L0.0150001 2.223C0.0831583 1.61164 0.374324 1.04687 0.832795 0.63674C1.29127 0.226607 1.88485 -9.6716e-05 2.5 3.09527e-08H13.5Z"/>
</svg>

<!-- icon 2 -->
<svg class="icon-2" viewBox="0 0 12 17" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M5.83333 7.91667C5.2808 7.91667 4.7509 7.69717 4.36019 7.30647C3.96949 6.91577 3.75 6.38587 3.75 5.83333C3.75 5.2808 3.96949 4.7509 4.36019 4.36019C4.7509 3.96949 5.2808 3.75 5.83333 3.75C6.38587 3.75 6.91577 3.96949 7.30647 4.36019C7.69717 4.7509 7.91667 5.2808 7.91667 5.83333C7.91667 6.10692 7.86278 6.37783 7.75808 6.63059C7.65339 6.88335 7.49993 7.11302 7.30647 7.30647C7.11302 7.49993 6.88335 7.65339 6.63059 7.75808C6.37783 7.86278 6.10692 7.91667 5.83333 7.91667V7.91667ZM5.83333 0C4.28624 0 2.80251 0.614582 1.70854 1.70854C0.614582 2.80251 0 4.28624 0 5.83333C0 10.2083 5.83333 16.6667 5.83333 16.6667C5.83333 16.6667 11.6667 10.2083 11.6667 5.83333C11.6667 4.28624 11.0521 2.80251 9.95812 1.70854C8.86416 0.614582 7.38043 0 5.83333 0V0Z"/>
</svg>
```

---

Если иконок много и с ними никаких сложным манипуляций делать не нужно, то можно создать спрайт, делается он следующим образом:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <!-- svg заменяем на symbol, убираем все кроме viewBox, и задаем id(название иконки)-->
   <symbol id="svg-mail" viewBox="0 0 16 13">
     <path d="M16 3.373V10.5C16 11.163 15.7366 11.7989 15.2678 12.2678C14.7989 12.7366 14.163 13 13.5 13H2.5C1.83696 13 1.20107 12.7366 0.732233 12.2678C0.263392 11.7989 0 11.163 0 10.5V3.373L7.746 7.931C7.82295 7.97638 7.91066 8.00032 8 8.00032C8.08934 8.00032 8.17705 7.97638 8.254 7.931L16 3.373ZM13.5 3.09527e-08C14.1151 -9.6716e-05 14.7087 0.226607 15.1672 0.63674C15.6257 1.04687 15.9168 1.61164 15.985 2.223L8 6.92L0.0150001 2.223C0.0831583 1.61164 0.374324 1.04687 0.832795 0.63674C1.29127 0.226607 1.88485 -9.6716e-05 2.5 3.09527e-08H13.5Z"/>
   </symbol>
  
  <symbol id="svg-point" viewBox="0 0 12 17">
    <path d="M5.83333 7.91667C5.2808 7.91667 4.7509 7.69717 4.36019 7.30647C3.96949 6.91577 3.75 6.38587 3.75 5.83333C3.75 5.2808 3.96949 4.7509 4.36019 4.36019C4.7509 3.96949 5.2808 3.75 5.83333 3.75C6.38587 3.75 6.91577 3.96949 7.30647 4.36019C7.69717 4.7509 7.91667 5.2808 7.91667 5.83333C7.91667 6.10692 7.86278 6.37783 7.75808 6.63059C7.65339 6.88335 7.49993 7.11302 7.30647 7.30647C7.11302 7.49993 6.88335 7.65339 6.63059 7.75808C6.37783 7.86278 6.10692 7.91667 5.83333 7.91667V7.91667ZM5.83333 0C4.28624 0 2.80251 0.614582 1.70854 1.70854C0.614582 2.80251 0 4.28624 0 5.83333C0 10.2083 5.83333 16.6667 5.83333 16.6667C5.83333 16.6667 11.6667 10.2083 11.6667 5.83333C11.6667 4.28624 11.0521 2.80251 9.95812 1.70854C8.86416 0.614582 7.38043 0 5.83333 0V0Z"/>
  </symbol>
  
</svg>
```

Сохраняем этот код в файл с любым названием, пусть будет **icons.svg** и используем на странице следующим образом:

```
<svg class="icon-1">
  <!-- assets/images/icons/icons.svg - путь до файла -->
  <!-- #svg-mail - id икноки -->
  <use xlink:href="assets/images/icons/icons.svg#svg-mail"></use>
</svg>

<svg class="icon-2">
  <use xlink:href="assets/images/icons/icons.svg#svg-point"></use>
</svg>
```

Либо можно не сохранять в файл и вставить код этого спрайта в начало страницы, скрыв его при этом с помощью `display: none`:

```css
svg {
  width: 10vmax;
  height: 10vmax;
}

.icon-1 {
  fill: tomato;
  transition: fill 0.4s;
}

.icon-1:hover {
  fill: lightgreen;
}

.icon-2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: tomato;
  transition: stroke 0.4s;
}

.icon-2:hover {
  stroke: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
   <symbol id="svg-mail" viewBox="0 0 16 13">
     <path d="M16 3.373V10.5C16 11.163 15.7366 11.7989 15.2678 12.2678C14.7989 12.7366 14.163 13 13.5 13H2.5C1.83696 13 1.20107 12.7366 0.732233 12.2678C0.263392 11.7989 0 11.163 0 10.5V3.373L7.746 7.931C7.82295 7.97638 7.91066 8.00032 8 8.00032C8.08934 8.00032 8.17705 7.97638 8.254 7.931L16 3.373ZM13.5 3.09527e-08C14.1151 -9.6716e-05 14.7087 0.226607 15.1672 0.63674C15.6257 1.04687 15.9168 1.61164 15.985 2.223L8 6.92L0.0150001 2.223C0.0831583 1.61164 0.374324 1.04687 0.832795 0.63674C1.29127 0.226607 1.88485 -9.6716e-05 2.5 3.09527e-08H13.5Z"/>
   </symbol>
  
  <symbol id="svg-point" viewBox="0 0 12 17">
    <path d="M5.83333 7.91667C5.2808 7.91667 4.7509 7.69717 4.36019 7.30647C3.96949 6.91577 3.75 6.38587 3.75 5.83333C3.75 5.2808 3.96949 4.7509 4.36019 4.36019C4.7509 3.96949 5.2808 3.75 5.83333 3.75C6.38587 3.75 6.91577 3.96949 7.30647 4.36019C7.69717 4.7509 7.91667 5.2808 7.91667 5.83333C7.91667 6.10692 7.86278 6.37783 7.75808 6.63059C7.65339 6.88335 7.49993 7.11302 7.30647 7.30647C7.11302 7.49993 6.88335 7.65339 6.63059 7.75808C6.37783 7.86278 6.10692 7.91667 5.83333 7.91667V7.91667ZM5.83333 0C4.28624 0 2.80251 0.614582 1.70854 1.70854C0.614582 2.80251 0 4.28624 0 5.83333C0 10.2083 5.83333 16.6667 5.83333 16.6667C5.83333 16.6667 11.6667 10.2083 11.6667 5.83333C11.6667 4.28624 11.0521 2.80251 9.95812 1.70854C8.86416 0.614582 7.38043 0 5.83333 0V0Z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<header></header>
<main>
  <svg class="icon-1">
    <use xlink:href="#svg-mail"></use>
  </svg>

  <svg class="icon-2">
    <use xlink:href="#svg-point"></use>
  </svg>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: @ᅠhᅠПривет! Давненько тебя не видел. Позволь уточнить, теги  `<symbol>` для этого и используются, чтобы не показывать содержимое, пока его не вызовут с помощью `<use>` поэтому `display:none;` излишне и даже вредно в некоторых комбинациях вызова иконок

Comment: @Alexandr_TT привет, извини пожалуйста

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/PojjGwg - смотри сам - почему в теге SVG стоит display: none